# Is there any way to use X509Store in .NET CF?

Tags: compact-framework

How to use X509Store in .NET CF? I have not found it on the Object Browser window.

Answer (score 0):

Will this do for you?

http://inthehand.com/library/html/N_InTheHand_Security_Cryptography_X509Certificates.htm