# Cannot resolve symbol x509store

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have this line of code:

```
X509Store certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
```

It works fine in a console project, but not in my Windows Phone project. In the Windows Phone project, X509store cannot be found.

Why not?

Answer (score 0):

For the .NET compact framework / Windows Phone apps, there is a solution here:

[Is there any way to use X509Store in .NET CF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908097/is-there-any-way-to-use-x509store-in-net-cf).

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but how do I download/install that library?

Answer (score 0):

[Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/) got you covered, check their site out. Download the source code, create new WP7 class library and add all files. It should compile. Do not copy tests folder since it depends on NUnit for testing, you won't be needing that.

What about the rest of your application, what do you want with certificates?